# Transparent color overlay on background image covers up the form fields

Tags: html, css

I am playing with transparent color overlay on top of form fields that also has background image specified.

The problem I am having is that either color overlay or background image sits on top of the form and blocks the access to the form fields.

```
.frame {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200) no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 50px 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.frame:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I've come across similar issues here regarding the combined use of `background-image` and `background-color` with transparency but I guess my scenario is a bit different with form fields in play.

This is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/zVqE2/7/) if you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was obvious, using `:after` to draw alpha over the background will miss the desired effect, because its not affecting the background alone but the element as an whole with everything inside it included.

But you can always do it the old fashion way, with multiple layers, each one with its own background. You can have an element with the image as background, and inside it create a new element with transparent background, and then you put your fields inside it.

And thats what you have:

http://jsfiddle.net/zVqE2/9/

Comment: Thanks very much. Sounds like a decent solution. How compatible is the alpha property by the way?

Comment: Well, all I can say is that it worked in IE 10, so if IE is supporting it pretty much anything is.

Comment: [RGBa is supported in FF3+, any version of Chrome, Safari 3+, IE9+, Opera 10+, and others](http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/). Actually not too bad.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.frame:after` is a new element (though it isn't shown in the HTML code), you're effectively putting a block-level element over the entirety of your form, which takes all the click events of your form. To combat this, you can make use of the CSS property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events), specifically setting it to `none`. This will effectively instruct all clicks to go through the element and affect whatever's below it.

```
.frame:after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;

    //add this!
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

### EDIT

If you're concerned about browser compatibility, simply switch the order of how you're applying the background image - set the background image on the pseudo-element and set its `z-index` to `-1`, and give the frame a transparent black background.

```
.frame {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);    
    width: 200px;
    padding: 50px 80px;
    position: relative;
}
.frame:after {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200) no-repeat;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1; /* put it behind the frame */
}
```

As [@Havenard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156811/havenard) pointed out, though, this could give you grief if your full website makes use of `z-index` for design purposes, and may require some other `z-index` values to be adjusted to work properly.

Comment: Browser compatibility is a concern. Thanks for the input though. Just so you know I didn't down vote...

Comment: On the contrary, [its support is fairly widespread besides IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @Nightfirecat That was me - and I did explain. Plus you downvoted mine.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's considered barely supported, when every standards-compliant browser (minus IE, who's still catching up) supports it. Also, if you look at the edit I made, I provided a **second** _fully correct_ solution. If that's still downvote-worthy, I'm not sure what impresses you.

Comment: And my downvote towards your answer was simply because after two attempts, you haven't created a correct example yet.

Comment: I like how you made it work by inverting the logic, but isn't `z-index` a little tricky to play with? In this fiddle exemple with no other variables to interfer it worked, but I think this may not have the desired effect in an actual website with probably other elements behind the form. The background can get hidden under some other element.

Comment: @Havenard That's correct - in a working environment, it would be wise to consider any other aspects of the website which would make use of `z-index`, and adjust the value to one which will work properly with it. On the upside, it does keep from using additional elements.

Comment: @Nightfirecat Thanks a lot. I appreciate it. Unfortunately other solution worked for my working setup. I guess I have too many elements that get in the way with z-index property.

Comment: @SeongLee Not unfortunate at all; glad Havenard's solution worked fine.